# Concourse CI windows/strict mime type checking

Tags: concourse

When running concourse ci v3.3.2 locally on Windows I get these errors:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://192.168.178.29:8080/public/index.js?id=932c553753eec4ef375e1c17f4b28c10' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.
>   192.168.178.29/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.178.29:8080/public/d3.v355.min.js?id=5936da7688d010c60aaf8374f90fcc2b' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.
>   192.168.178.29/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.178.29:8080/public/graph.js?id=3e2a3f561ec6c52216e80266ef0212d2' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.
>   192.168.178.29/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.178.29:8080/public/jquery-2.1.1.min.js?id=e40ec2161fe7993196f23c8a07346306'
>   because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.
>   192.168.178.29/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.178.29:8080/public/concourse.js?id=b4688d002041187f6c55f6e8699442ba' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled. (index):1 Refused to execute script
>   from
>   'http://192.168.178.29:8080/public/elm.min.js?id=d38f054604f3aaf5cd4eb0616b3cb3ef' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled. (index):20 Uncaught ReferenceError: Elm
>   is not defined
>       at (index):20

It's probably something obvious but couldn't find anything on google/stack overflow for these errors in combination with Concourse

Comment: Please give some more context:
Where are these errors being displayed? What were you trying to do? How do you have concourse setup?

Comment: Essentially I followed the install guide with the windows executable. Got that in chromes error log with empty gray page in the browser

Comment: Do you have an anti-virus?

Comment: Windows 10 which comes with defender.